# Nth function with list SASS

Tags: css, list, function, sass, each

Having problems with adding the right input type. Want to make sure the right input type is inserted. Thinking maybe it is the way I set the value or maybe the way retrieving the value is wrong. Any help, please.

```
$login_icon: 20px;
$login_font-size: 30px;
$la-user: "\f364";
$la-pass: "\f271";
$la-envelope: "\f1c7";
$form_name: #username #password #email;
$input_type: text password text;
$icon_name: $la-user $la-pass $la-envelope;

@each $current-col in $form_name {
    $i: index($form_name, $current-col);
    #{$current-col}-element {
        background: red;
        input[type="#{$input_val}"] {
            background: pink;
        }
    }
    #{$current-col}-label {
        color: $current-col;
        content: nth($icon_name, $i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the accompanying HTML that you are applying the styling to?

Comment: Yeah, where are you defining `$input_val` ? It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere in your code, it's only referenced when you try to pull the value out.